# how can i have only one result in a query with manytomany field?

Tags: django

user 1 have option A and C,
user 2 have option A and B

if user A is logued, he can see this

- option A -  you have
- option B -  you like this? (with a button for add)
- option C -  you have
- option D -  you like this? (with a button for add)
- option E -  you like this? (with a button for add)

if user 2 is logued, he can see this

- option A -  you have
- option B -  you have
- option C -  you like this? (with a button for add)
- option D -  you like this? (with a button for add)
- option E -  you like this? (with a button for add)

but only can do this:

if user 1 is logued:

- option A -  you have - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option B -  you like this? (with a button for add) - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option C -  you have - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option D -  you like this? (with a button for add) - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option E -  you like this? (with a button for add) - you like this? (with a button for add)

and user 2 :

- option A -  you have - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option B -  you have - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option C -  you like this? (with a button for add) - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option D -  you like this? (with a button for add) - you like this? (with a button for add)
- option E -  you like this? (with a button for add)

my models:

```
class Options(models.Model):
    option_titulo = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

my view:

```
def ListaOptions(request):
    userid=request.user.id
    options=Options.objects.all()
    opt_user=Options.objects.filter(user__id=userid)

    return render_to_response(
      'options.html',
       {
        'options': options,
        'opt_user': opt_user,
       },
       context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                )
```

my template:

```
 {% for o in options %}

   {{ o.option_titulo }} - 

   {% for u in opt_user %}

     {% if u.id == o.id %}
      you have
     {% else %}
      you like this? (with a button for add)
     {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `in` for each option to test if it's in `opt_user`:

```
{% for o in options %}
    {{ o.option_titulo }} - 
    {% if o in opt_user %}
        you have
    {% else %}
        you like this? (with a button for add)
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```